# AutoHotkey: create a hotkey with 3 keys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a hotkey with 3 keys, for example "control + k + l"
Let's say I have the following script:

> ^k&l::
>      Click, 55, 100
>      Click, 55, 750
>   Return

This code won't function since "&" doesn't work with 3 keys.
How can I create such a hotkey anyways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with such combined multikeys hotkeys is that some keyboard don't support scan codes of such key presses. Try it different way:

```
#^k::  ; WindowsKey+Ctrl+k
Input key, I L1

IfEqual key,l ; Release WindowsKey+Ctrl+k and press l
  MsgBox You pressed WindowsKey+Control+k+l

IfEqual key,i ; Release WindowsKey+Ctrl+k and press i
  MsgBox You pressed WindowsKey+Control+k+i
Return
```

I used `WindowsKey+Ctrl` as prefix because <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> already occupied in many cases. Above are two hotkeys that can be activated as simultaneous pressing <kbd>WinKey+Ctrl+k</kbd>
then release it and press <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>